# How to run through every integer point in a circle given center (x,y) and radius r?

Tags: java, math

I tried the code below with r = 10 and the print statement ran 12 times instead of my expected 20 since the diameter of the circle aligns with the center.

```
public void testPoints(int x, int y, int r){
    for(int i = 0; i < 360; i++){
        if((int) Math.round(x+r*Math.cos(i)) == x){
            System.out.println("Hi");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Math.cos(x)` - x should be in radians.

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#cos(double)). It says the argument should be in radians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in method to convert to radians.

```
public void testPoints(int x, int y, int r){
    for(int i = 0; i < 360; i++){
        if(Math.round(x+r*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i))) == x){
            System.out.println("Hi");
        }
    }
}
```

Or Just start off with Radians in your loop

```
    public static void testPoints(int x, int y, int r){
        double maxAngle = 2*Math.PI;
        double increment = maxAngle/360.;
        for(double i = 0; i < maxAngle; i += increment){
            if(Math.round(x+r*Math.cos(i)) == x){
                System.out.println("Hi");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you missed here is that the function expects the angle to be in radians and not degrees. To fix that, simply convert the angle in degrees to radians. You can achieve that by using this:

```
if ((int) Math.round(x+r*Math.cos((i*Math.PI)/180)) == x){
      System.out.println("Hi");
}
```

Comment: Or you use `Math.PI`, it exists for a reason. Or even better, `Math#toRadians(double)`.

Comment: @Polygnome Thank you for the suggestion! I agree with you and corrected my answer. Also, Math.toRadians() has already been used in the answer above.